# Bulk renaming of files based on lookup

Tags: python, perl, bash

I have a folder full of image files such as

- 1500000704_full.jpg
- 1500000705_full.jpg
- 1500000711_full.jpg
- 1500000712_full.jpg
- 1500000714_full.jpg
- 1500000744_full.jpg
- 1500000745_full.jpg
- 1500000802_full.jpg
- 1500000803_full.jpg

I need to rename the files based on a lookup from a text file which has entries such as,

- SH103239 1500000704
- SH103240 1500000705
- SH103241 1500000711
- SH103242 1500000712
- SH103243 1500000714
- SH103244 1500000744
- SH103245 1500000745
- SH103252 1500000802
- SH103253 1500000803
- SH103254 1500000804

So, I want the image files to be renamed,

- SH103239_full.jpg
- SH103240_full.jpg
- SH103241_full.jpg
- SH103242_full.jpg
- SH103243_full.jpg
- SH103244_full.jpg
- SH103245_full.jpg
- SH103252_full.jpg
- SH103253_full.jpg
- SH103254_full.jpg

How can I do this job the easiest? Any one can write me a quick command or script which can do this for me please? I have a lot of these image files and manual change isnt feasible.

I am on ubuntu but depending on the tool I can switch to windows if need be. Ideally I would love to have it in bash script so that I can learn more or simple perl or python.

Thanks

EDIT: Had to Change the file names

Comment: Is there the same number of entries in the lookup file as there are image files?

Comment: There are more images than the number of entries in the file

Comment: Then iterating over the entries is more efficient than iterating over the files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a simple Python 2 script to do the rename.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

# A dict with keys being the old filenames and values being the new filenames
mapping = {}

# Read through the mapping file line-by-line and populate 'mapping'
with open('mapping.txt') as mapping_file:
    for line in mapping_file:
        # Split the line along whitespace
        # Note: this fails if your filenames have whitespace
        new_name, old_name = line.split()
        mapping[old_name] = new_name

suffix = '_full'

# List the files in the current directory
for filename in os.listdir('.'):
    root, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
    if not root.endswith(suffix):
        # File doesn't end with this suffix; ignore it
        continue
    # Strip off the number of characters that make up suffix
    stripped_root = root[:-len(suffix)]
    if stripped_root in mapping:
        os.rename(filename, ''.join(mapping[stripped_root] + suffix + extension))
```

Various bits of the script are hard-coded that really shouldn't be. These include the name of the mapping file (`mapping.txt`) and the filename suffix (`_full`). These could presumably be passed in as arguments and interpreted using `sys.argv`.

Comment: Hi, can you give me some details on how I should run this script. When I run this, nothing happens. My mapping.txt file is as in the original post above. Any hints would be great.

Comment: Sorry, never mind. I was running another script. This works great. Thanks.

Comment: No, **nice and simple** is `perl -lane 'rename("$F[1].jpg", "$F[0].jpg")' mapping.txt`.  Sheesh!

Comment: Hey Wesley, Thank you for the script. Can you please help me to make adjustment to the script since the image file names have "_full" in the end. Script runs assuming my mapping file has the same file names....I have edited the main post to show what I mean....Sorry about me not being clear.

Comment: This should just about do what you're asking for. Give that a shot.

Comment: Sweet.....Thanks a lot!!!!! You have saved me hours of manual work. I promise I will study and learn how to form such scripts soon. Untill then thanks awesome community.

Answer (score 5):

This will work for your problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
while (<DATA>) {
    my($new, $old) = split;
    rename("$old.jpg", "$new.jpg")
        || die "can't rename "$old.jpg", "$new.jpg": $!";
}
__END__
SH103239 1500000704
SH103240 1500000705
SH103241 1500000711
SH103242 1500000712
SH103243 1500000714
SH103244 1500000744
SH103245 1500000745
SH103252 1500000802
SH103253 1500000803
SH103254 1500000804
```

Switch to `ARGV` from `DATA` to read the lines from a particular input file.

Normally for mass rename operations, I use something more like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# rename script by Larry Wall
#
# eg:
#      rename 's/\.orig$//'  *.orig
#      rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/ unless /^Make/'  *
#      rename '$_ .= ".bad"'  *.f
#      rename 'print "$_: "; s/foo/bar/ if <STDIN> =~ /^y/i'  *
#      find /tmp -name '*~' -print | rename 's/^(.+)~$/.#$1/'

($op = shift) || die "Usage: rename expr [files]\n";

chomp(@ARGV = <STDIN>) unless @ARGV;

for (@ARGV) {
    $was = $_;
    eval $op;
    die if $@;  # means eval `failed'
    rename($was,$_) unless $was eq $_;
}
```

I’ve a more full-featured version, but that should suffice.

Comment: can we have the more full-featured version that you have for our usage. this might be useful for other users too... of what else your script can do. like mkdir etc. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

for FILE in *.jpg; do
    OLD=${FILE%.*}  # Strip off extension.
    NEW=$(awk -v "OLD=$OLD" '$2==OLD {print $1}' map.txt)
    mv "$OLD.jpg" "$NEW.jpg"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

A rewrite of Wesley's using generators:

```
import os, os.path

with open('mapping.txt') as mapping_file:
    mapping = dict(line.strip().split() for line in mapping_file)

rootextiter = ((filename, os.path.splitext(filename)) for filename in os.listdir('.'))
mappediter = (
    (filename, os.path.join(mapping[root], extension))
    for filename, root, extension in rootextiter
    if root in mapping
)
for oldname, newname in mappediter:
    os.rename(oldname, newname)
```

Comment: Nasty. Maybe I haven't been doing python long enough (four or five years!), but this is completely unreadable to me.

Comment: @Graeme Perrow: read David Beazley on generators, Changed my life. http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/

Answer (score 2):

This is very straightforward to do in Bash assuming that there's an entry in the lookup file for each file and each file has a lookup entry.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r to from
do
    if [ -e "${from}_full.jpg" ]
    then
        mv "${from}_full.jpg" "${to}_full.jpg"
    fi
done < lookupfile.txt
```

If the lookup file has many more entries than there are files then this approach may be inefficient. If the reverse is true then an approach that iterates over the files may be inefficient. However, if the numbers are close then this may be the best approach since it doesn't have to actually do any lookups.

If you'd prefer a lookup version that's pure-Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r to from
do
    lookup[from]=$to
done < lookupfile.txt

for file in *.jpg
do
    base=${file%*_full.jpg}
    mv "$file" "${lookup[base]}_full.jpg"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

I modified Wesley's Code to work for my specific situation. I had a mapping file "sort.txt" that consisted of different .pdf files and numbers to indicate the order that I want them in based on an output from DOM manipulation from a website. I wanted to combine all these separate pdf files into a single pdf file but I wanted to retain the same order they are in as they are on the website. So I wanted to append numbers according to their tree location in a navigation menu.

```
1054 spellchecking.pdf
1055 using-macros-in-the-editor.pdf
1056 binding-macros-with-keyboard-shortcuts.pdf
1057 editing-macros.pdf
1058 etc........
```

Here is the Code I came up with:

```
import os, sys

# A dict with keys being the old filenames and values being the new filenames
mapping = {}

# Read through the mapping file line-by-line and populate 'mapping'
with open('sort.txt') as mapping_file:
    for line in mapping_file:

        # Split the line along whitespace
        # Note: this fails if your filenames have whitespace
        new_name, old_name = line.split()
        mapping[old_name] = new_name


# List the files in the current directory
for filename in os.listdir('.'):
    root, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)

    #rename, put number first to allow for sorting by name and 
    #then append original filename +e extension
    if filename in mapping:
        print "yay" #to make coding fun
        os.rename(filename, mapping[filename] + filename + extension)
```

I didn't have a suffix like _full so I didn't need that code. Other than that its the same code, I've never really touched python so this was a good learning experience for me.

Answer (score 1):

Read in the text file, create a hash with the current file name, so `files['1500000704'] = 'SH103239'` and so on. Then go through the files in the current directory, grab the new filename from the hash, and rename it.

Comment: Subscripting an array with a string?

Comment: See @Wesley's answer for code similar to what I hadn't yet gotten to write.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fun little hack:

```
paste -d " " lookupfile.txt lookupfile.txt | cut -d " " -f 2,3 | sed "s/\([ ]\|$\)/_full.jpg /g;s/^/mv /" | sh
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os,re,sys

mapping = <Insert your mapping here> #Dictionary Key value entries (Lookup)

for k,v in mapping:
    for f in os.listdir("."):
        if re.match('1500',f): #Executes code on specific files
            os.rename(f,f.replace(k,v))
```