# Renaming bulk of files

Tags: python, awk, sed

I have many files like med_001.txt, med_002.txt,...,med_020.txt.

How could I change the names of the files as med_021.txt, med_022.txt,...,med_040.txt respectively?

I  used 'mv' or 'rename' command but it was quite tedious.

Comment: Possible dup. [Bulk renaming of files based on lookup](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4140619/1982962)

Comment: Is it for a project or just for once? In case you need only to rename those files, have you considered gprename?

Comment: I do not ask project/homework questions. I am rearranging my folders and files for future uses.

Answer (score 1):

In Python.

This script first moves the renamed files from the current directory to a temporary directory (created by the script), and then moves them back to the current directory. This avoids possible overwrites if moves are performed in the same directory, e.g. if file med_001.txt and med_021.txt exist, renaming med_001.txt to med_021.txt will result in the trashing of the orginal med_021.txt.

```
import os
import shutil
from glob import glob
from tempfile import mkdtemp

GLOB_PATTERN = 'med_[0-9][0-9][0-9].txt'

# move renamed files to temporary directory
temp_dir = mkdtemp()
for f in glob(GLOB_PATTERN):
    new_filename = 'med_%03d.txt' % (int(f[-7:-4])+20)    # very specific to this question - could use regex instead
    shutil.move(f, os.path.join(temp_dir, new_filename))

for f in glob(os.path.join(temp_dir, '*')):
    shutil.move(f, '.') # move back to current directory

# clean up
os.rmdir(temp_dir)
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. I am using 2.7.5 version of python. When I executed the code, 'OSError: [Errno 18] Invalid cross-device link' message was seen.

Comment: Try using `shutil.move()` instead of `os.rename()`. I have updated the answer with this change.

Answer (score 0):

This script should do the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o noclobber
mkdir tmp$$
for i in med_*.txt
do
   [[ $i =~ med_[0]*([1-9][0-9]*).txt ]]
   s=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
   let s+=20
   cmd=$(printf "mv $i tmp$$/med_%03d.txt" $s)
   $($cmd)
done
for i in tmp$$/*.txt
do
   $(mv $i .)
done
rmdir tmp$$
```

Comment: This is unsafe. It will overwrite existing files named with a sequence 20 more than another file, e.g. if there are files med_001.txt and med_021.txt, med_021.txt will be overwritten and then, later, it will also be moved to med_041.txt, possibly trashing another file. This can cascade into obliterating any sequence of files with names offest by 20.

Comment: @mhawke I fixed the problem.  Thankyou for spotting it.

Comment: That's a little better, but there still is a problem. What if the file is `med_021.txt` and there also exists a file named `_041.txt` in the same directory? It will be overwritten. Also, any files matching `_*.txt` (e.g. _abcd.txt) will be renamed and prefixed with `med_`. It's safer to use a fresh directory.

Comment: Ok @mhawke. Better to fix it and burn this stuff into my brain for next time.

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple command?

```
for i in 1 2 3;do let j=$i+20;mv med_00${i}.txt med_0${j}.txt;done
```