# Files bulk renaming - match a predefined text file

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-rename

Good day,

I am trying to rename/organize files based on the match/lookup found in the text file.

I have a couple of hundred Cyrillic(Russian) named media files in a folder like this:

- файл 35.avi
- файл34.avi
- файл2 4.avi
- файл14.avi

*note that some files have spaces

The text file, with the desired names, looks like this:

- файл 35.avi| **4.** файл 35.avi
- файл34.avi| **3.** файл34.avi
- файл2 4.avi| **1.** файл2 4.avi
- файл14.avi| **2.** файл14.avi

The reason it looks that way (with | as a separator) is because I tried using "Bulk Renaming Utility" which uses pipe | as a separator for "Rename Pairs" function. So essentially, the filename to the right of pipe | is the final product. Unfortunately, that function does not work with Cyrillic(Russian) or other non standard characters.

I found PowerShell script [HERE](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/11/22/use-powershell-to-rename-files-in-bulk/) which  appears to be almost what I need except that it does not match file names before renaming.
Similarly, I found this Python script [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140619/bulk-renaming-of-files-based-on-lookup) which does what i need but it's for Ubuntu. Unfortunately, I am on a Windows7 and not sure it applies to me.

Any recommendations?

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: why you can't use *bulk renaming utility* one more time, but to do it the right way this time?

Comment: Not sure if there is a different way to do it with BRU. Can you suggest the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read the text file into a hashtable, where the key is the old name (the value on the left hand side of the `|`), and the value is the new name:

```
$RenameTable = @{}
Get-Content textfile.txt |ForEach-Object {
    $OldName,$NewName = $_.Split('|')
    $RenameTable[$OldName] = $NewName
}
```

Then rename the files based on what is in the hashtable:

```
Get-ChildItem .\folder\with\avi\files |Rename-Item -NewName {
    if($RenameTable.ContainsKey($_.Name)){ 
        $RenameTable[$_.Name] 
    } else { 
        $_.Name 
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe use `Get-ChildItem $ScriptDir -Filter *.avi |...` to only attempt renaming the avi files, but yes, otherwise that should be fine