# Bulk renaming of files with white spaces in names, based on lookup, keeping folder structure

Tags: python-3.x

I have 12000 PDF files in a folder structure and a lookup csv file to rename them, keeping the structure. I found

[Bulk renaming of files based on lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140619/bulk-renaming-of-files-based-on-lookup)

but white spaces in names wasn't dealt with, and I did not find anything to be able to go through the entire folder tree structure and rename the files according to the lookup table while mantaining the folder structure.

Any ideas please?
Thanks

Comment: can you give an example of: The names of PDF (like 5 or so) and their corresponding counterparts from lookup csv?

Comment: Hi Rushi, thanks for asking. here is just one example: "13_07 Daimler Korres17.pdf" = "Antwort1 Daimler 13_17_2017.pdf". This is a coincidence, that the same word appears in the old AND the new name. That is not always the case, and also the sequence of characters is not always the same. So, there really is no system of deriving the new name from the old name. One would just have to use the lookup table. We could create an sqlite file from csv to speed up the lookup, so we could read the file name and get the new name quite quickly but code to go through all the folders seems to be tricky, no?

Answer (score 0):

**When there are white spaces in file names, you should use double quotes around them or escape white spaces within them.**

For what you want to do, you can reuse the following `zsh` script.

It takes as argument the directory to be worked upon.  Try on some small unimportant directory first. To avoid doing wrong, I have set up a dialog and facilitated the reverse renaming.

Files to be renamed are selected with the globing feature of `zsh`. You need to adapt this to your case. I make an array of the file list (with parenthesis), so I don't have to worry about the file separator.

You should adapt the `from` and `to` variables or more generally the `sed` substitution rule.  You could transform your csv file into a sed script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

from=RIB;to=IBAN
## reverse
#from=IBAN;to=RIB

filelist=($1/**/$from*.(pdf|jpg|jpeg|PDF|JPG|JPEG))

zip(){
    for file in $filelist
    do
    $1 "$file" "`echo $file|sed -E "s/(.*)$from(.*)/\1$to\2/"`"
    done}

# dry run
zip echo

read -q -s $'REPLY?Do you want to rename as above ?\n'
[[ $REPLY != y ]] && {echo "Not renaming and exiting.";exit}

echo "Renaming..."
zip mv
echo "Renamed."
```